# Louis Couturat on inclusive disjunction in Ido

Tags: constructed-language, logic

In Ido, the constructed language he helped to build, Louis Couturat attempted to introduce **vel**, a conjunction that would express *[inclusive disjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction)*—so that, in logical sentences, the conjunction **o(d)** would express *[exclusive disjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or)*.

Louis Couturat was a logician who corresponded with Bertrand Russell. For some time, the conjuction **vel** was adopted by the Ido Academy and people started using it. However, in *Progreso*, the official Ido magazine, Couturat argued that Idists were using **vel** incorrectly. For instance, somewhere one could read: "We offer gratis [vel] not gratis books". He argued that the use of **vel** in that sentence is wrong, since a book cannot be gratis and not gratis *at the same time*. Similarly, he said that "in the daytime [vel] in the nighttime" is illogical, since day and night cannot exist *at the same time*. However, he gave this sentence as a "good" example: "We are looking for someone who speaks German [vel] Ido", saying that German and Ido *can* coexist *at the same time*.

So my question is: was Louis Couturat right when he implied that the inclusive disjunction must be valid for *each* element of a group considered individually (i.e. a *single* book cannot be gratis *and* not gratis), and not only for *all* elements considered as a whole (i.e. *some* books can be gratis while *the others* are not)?

Comment: Surely what is called for in the first example would simply be conjunction? "We offer free and not free books."

Comment: Yes, all instances where I wrote [vel] can be translated to a conjunction that expresses inclusive disjunction. As far as I know, in English it is “or” (not “and” nor the popular “and/or”), and in French it is “ou” (not “et” nor “et/ou”). So when someone asks “Do you speak French or English?”, the respondent can answer “Both”. In the case of “Do you speak French and English”, the answer would be “Yes”. In the case of an exclusive “or”—which would sound absurd in that context—the answer would be “No”. Did I answer your question?

Comment: My question is about the fact that Couturat said that the inclusive disjunction is inappropriate in the first and second examples. I would like to know whether he was right and why.

Comment: What I meant was, conjunction without any type of disjunction. Presumably both types of books are on offer. Inclusive disjunction seems like it would mean either one type, or the other type, or both types are on offer. I guess it could be a "free choice" disjunction, though, like "Do you want sugar or tea in your coffee?"

Comment: This has nothing to do with correctness in Ido, if there is any such thing. Couturat introduced the word, after all. He gets to say if it's right or not. The logical use of exclusive `OR` (Truth Table FTTF) instead of inclusive `OR` (Truth Table TTTF) differs only in the first line of the truth table. If both P and Q are True, then inclusive `P OR Q` is True, while exclusive `P OR Q` is False.  _Vel_ is another matter entirely, as are Couturat's motives.

Comment: @jlawler Thank you for the logical terms, it helps me conceptualize the problem. I never mentioned this problem to be exclusive to correctness *in Ido*, since I think that such logic goes beyond the boundaries of a single language. Otherwise, I think my question would have been off-topic in this community.

Comment: `XOR` is alive and well in computer design; there's an enormous literature. But in natural language it rarely makes a difference whether both alternatives are true or not. In many case it's impossible, and in others it doesn't matter because it's outside the context. I don't know of any natural language with both an inclusive and an exclusive word for _or_; normally we just use one and let anybody who cares figure it out for themself.

Comment: @jlawler Thanks for the information. Couturat was a logician, so I guess he thought “vel” would be useful in his branch. Otherwise, as you wrote, there is little need for a distinction with exclusive disjunction in practical life thanks to context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Ido coordinating conjunctions have ambiguous scope like English conjunctions, then it will be possible for logically coherent sentences to include sequences like "gratis vel not gratis" or "in the daytime vel in the nighttime."

Let's consider the example "gratis [vel] not gratis books". In the corresponding English phrase "free or not free books", "free" and "not free" do not refer to the same things. There is an ellipsis; this really means "gratis *books* vel not gratis books." And this is a reasonable thing to offer, if you mean to emphasize that a customer can make either a selection composed entirely of free books, or a selection composed entirely of not-free books, or a selection composed of both free and not-free books. In other words, the idea expressed is "either [free books], or [not-free books], or both," which is not logically incorrect and which is a disjunction. (I actually do think it sounds better to just use simple conjunction, though. I don't quite understand the logical underpinnings of how free-choice disjunctives work, and it seems simpler to me to just talk about what is offered in general and say that it includes "(both) free **and** non-free books.")

"In the daytime, or in the nighttime, or both" is a very unlikely thing to want to express, so I agree that it is likely that someone using "vel" in this context is making an error. But again, in English at least it might make sense if the conjunction is really operating on a wider scope, for example "If [you like hiking in the daytime] vel [(*you like hiking*) in the nightime], you will find it helpful to have a map."

Comment: Thank you for the interpretation! You mentioned *ellipsis*, and I think it is the central explanation to Couturat's comments: he considered the first example without acknowledging the ellipsis. I think that's odd, since he did acknowledge the ellipsis in other features of Ido, such as *ka ne*. The latter expresses the same idea as *isn't it* and others at the end of sentences in English, e.g. *You like chocolate, don't you (like chocolate)?*. So ellipses do exist in Ido and are not generally seen as erroneous.

Comment: I guess he saw *vel* differently, since in *ka ne* the ellipsis is outside the main sentence (so it's as if they were two isolated propositions). Otherwise I think your explanation is clear and shows "free or not free books" is correct, at least from the point of view of English.